# JSP-web app Email notification on signup and account verification

Tags: jsp, jakarta-mail, email-verification

I am developing a web application with a jsp-based backend for the functionalities. So far, any user can register and login on the fly without any procedural steps in between. In order to make the web app more authentic, I would like to have a feature whereby a user signs up and receives an email notification that gives them a welcome message and a link that verifies their account. What would be the best pseudo code to work with and how would I integrate my sign up form with the email server that sends the notification email to the user?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javax.mail API for sending email notifications. The following is fully functional code that  uses an activation key.

```
public static void sendMail(String toAddress,String user,String psw, String key){

    final String msg = "<html><body><h3>** THIS IS AN AUTOMATED MESSAGE - PLEASE, DO NOT REPLY **</h3>This e-mail has been sent to you automatically as part of the registration process.<br> "
            +"To activate your account, click the activation link below.<br><br>"+key+"</body></html>"; 
    Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
    final String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "mail.dom.info");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtps.auth", "true");      
    properties.put("mail.smtps.quitwait", "false");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
    try{
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toAddress));

         message.setSubject("Your account activation");
        // message.setText(msg, "utf-8");
         message.setContent(msg, "text/html");  
         message.setSentDate(new Date());
         SMTPTransport transport = (SMTPTransport)session.getTransport("smtps");

         transport.connect("mail.dom.info", user, psw);
         transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());      
         transport.close();
         //System.out.println("Message sent....");
      }catch (MessagingException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

Note that you have to specify your SMTP server (in this case mail.dom.info) as well as the user name and password for the server (you should get this information from your web hosting provider). The last parameter is the activation key.

This example also uses HTML encoding for the message.

Answer (score 0):

```
Apache Commons Email API is also available for sending E-Mail.

If you have gmail account than these are few gmail account SMTP configuration using this you can send E-mail.

Gmail SMTP server name: smtp.gmail.com


Gmail SMTP username: your Gmail address


Gmail SMTP password: your password


Gmail SMTP port: 465

using this configuration you can send email using your gmail account. For other service provider you have to find its SMTP settings and provide in your api configuration.

Using apache commons api its quite easy like this :

Email email = new SimpleEmail();
email.setHostName("smtp.googlemail.com");
email.setSmtpPort(465);
email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("username", "password"));
email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
email.setFrom("user@gmail.com");
email.setSubject("TestMail");
email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)");
email.addTo("foo@bar.com");
email.send();


You can find more example from this : [1]:https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/userguide.html
```